# Crawl Properties & Managed Properties for my lookup site column's Title. why this is not being managed automatically

Tags: lookup-column, crawling, managed-property, crawled-property

I am working on 2 lists inside my sharepoint enterprise server 2013. the list are:-

1. Departments
2. Project

where the Project list have a lookup field (named ProjectDepartment) to the Department list , as follow:-
[image]

and inside the Project list i found 2 list columns representing the lookup site column (seems the `ProjectDepartment:Title` has been created automatically):-

[image]

now i am trying to build a content search web part, which will show  Projects that are under certain Departments. but my problem is that i am unable to find the related managed property representing the ProjectDepartment loojup column inside the search service.

i search these places:-

1- Central Admin >> Search Service >> Search Schema>> Managed Property>>search for the word "project". i got this , where the `ProjectDepartments` is not there:-

[image]

2- Central Admin >> Search Service >> Search Schema>> crawl properties. i got this , where the `ProjectDepartments` is there but not sure if this is the one i am searching for also i got `Sharepoint:title`:-

[image]

now what i am looking for is the ProjectDepartment Title inside the Project list ,, so which one i need to use ? and should i manually create a managed property for the lookup field? baring in mind that both the Project & Department lists contain data and i run a full crawl , and i am using SP 2013 where managed properties will be created automatically on all the site columns that contain data,, but seems this is not true when it comes to lookup columns..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ows_ProjectDapartment is very likely the crawled property you are looking for. You will need to manually create the managed property for Lookup column as it is not created automatically.

See this [Technet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj613136.aspx)

Comment: thanks for the link were it mentioned the following "_ Automatic creation of managed properties is not supported for the following site column types Lookup_" but does this mean that i can simply create them manually or there is a reason why managed properties are not been created for lookup columns?

Comment: second question, now inside our test server i created a managed property for the "_ows_ProjectDapartment_" and i was able to query the dept title inside the Project list, but not sure if this is the valid appraoch. as i also find a crawled property named "_SharePoint:title_" and when i click on it, i found that it have the following name "_ows_ProjectDepartments:Title_". but when i create a managed property for it i was NOT able to query the dept title for the projects. so what does  the "_ows_ProjectDepartments:Title_" crawl property represent? can you adivce on my 2 points please?

Comment: can you please adivce on my above comment?thx